# Access 2010 - Hyperlinks alias on a form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table that contains report URL's (http:...), and I need it to display it on a form.  How do I assign an "Alias" to the URL so that it will not display the entire URL on the form?

For example, http://report1.com Form display should be: Report 1 (with hyperlink)

Comment: Did you have a chance to try out my suggestion?

Comment: Yes by using VBA code Application.FollowHyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `Label` to the form
2. Set the `Caption` property to be your "Alias" `Report 1`
3. Set the `HyperlinkAddress` property to the URL

You can also do this dynamically in VBA code if you're using a recordset

[MSDN Reference Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/label-hyperlinkaddress-property-access)